# Buttons Doesnt Clear TextBox (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++

So I have created a WinForms (C#)
I added a *textbox* and a *button*, I have put this code on button: **"textbox1.clear();"**.
But it didn't work, timer doesnt work also like making a spam bot:?
What am i doing wrong? ***Thx for help***

Comment: What you're doing wrong is 1st , not showing us full code of the problem / issue and you need to read up on C# basics as well as how to use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using textbox1.Text.Clear() or simply textbox1.Text=""

Comment: if you found the answer useful, please mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Much like Monish Koyott said, you would need to use

```
textbox1.Text.Clear();
```

Or you could use

```
textbox1.Text = "";
```

Both of these will clear the textbox.

As far as your question about timers, I would use [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com) or use [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com)

If you had a question about TextBox I would start with googling "TextBox C#" and the same goes for about all other questions you would have. Only after you've searched for a bit should you come here to ask. Good luck with coding :)